# Postgres 12 Tuning Configuration for heavily transaction server, have I set values too low?

Tags: postgresql

We have a postgres 12 environment. Which has 130GB of RAM and 32 CPUs, have been monitoring the memory usage of the server in recent months and it uses around half of the memory on the server, I understand that making shared_buffers changes involves a restart but if effective_cache_size is changed do I need to do shared_buffers at same time (know dont need to restart for effective_cache_size just reload).

The server is a heavily transactional system.

Some of the important postgres configuration:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
max_connections = 1000
effective_cache_size = 60GB
shared_buffers = 25GB
temp_buffers = 32MB
max_prepared_transactions = 1000
work_mem = 256MB
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB

effective_io_concurrency = 200
random_page_cost = 1.1

max_worker_processes = 14
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 7
max_parallel_workers = 14
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 7

wal_level = logical
wal_buffers = 1MB
checkpoint_timeout = 5min
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
max_wal_senders = 6
max_wal_size = 4GB
min_wal_size = 256MB
wal_keep_segments = 400
wal_sender_timeout = 5min
wal_receiver_timeout = 5min
max_replication_slots = 6
```

I also have a replica slave server which has slightly less resources would this make any difference?

I have seen that the recommendation for shared_buffers is half or more of the server.

Apart from shared_buffers being altered to a higher value, the server doesnt use more memory (60GB out of 130GB and Swap at 5GB/14GB)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: "*The server is a heavily transactional system.*' - How heavy?...i.e. how many rows are being written per minute (or whatever time unit you find suitable)? How big is the database itself?

Comment: `effective_cache_size` does not "allocate" any memory. It's merely a hint to the optimizer how likely some block will be in the (file system) cache.

Comment: "have been monitoring the memory usage of the server"  How?  Does this monitoring assess filesystem cache usage?

Comment: How many queries are running at any given moment?  How many parallel workers at any given moment?

Comment: If you have 32 real CPUs (not "virtual" CPUs), then 14 would seem too low for max_*workers.  But that doesn't matter unless your queries are such that they would actually benefit from parallel workers.

Comment: @J.D. if I look over an hour there is approx 100,000 queries during that time. Databases combined are over 1.5TB approximately 5% of those are INSERT/UPDATES with the rest being read queries.

Comment: @jjanes is the recommendation for it being at 60GB too low, have seen examples of people setting it at 3/4 of Total RAM, this is a physical server. Monitoring via usual basic monitoring system, could see the servers memory was approx half used throughout a 6 month duration. With regards to parallel_workers some big SELECTs use parallel_workers.

Comment: This is turning into discussion, theorizing and so on. I'll vote to close.

Comment: effective_cache_size mostly matters for very large queries.  Each backend assumes it has this space all to itself, so if you have multiple very large queries running at the same time (which would usually be described as analytical, not transactional), you shouldn't set it to most of RAM as they might all choose plans which will drive each others data out of cache.  It is just not very effective as a tuning knob in general, only in specific cases, and it doesn't seem likely that it applies to you.

Answer (score 2):

I'll go through your settings and point out where I think there is room for improvement. A assume you have local SSD storage or similar.

- `max_connections = 1000`

  Not a good idea with 32 cores; the default 100 is ample. Use a connection pool and limit its size to something slightly above 32 - read [this](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/estimating-connection-pool-size-with-postgresql-database-statistics/) for more details.
- `max_prepared_transactions = 1000`

  Only if you *know* you need prepared transactions, and certainly not 1000. Prepared transactions are a health risk for your database.
- `work_mem = 256MB`

  Very high for transactional workload, but that won't do any harm.
- `effective_io_concurrency = 200`
  `random_page_cost = 1.1`

  Local SSD, right?
- `max_worker_processes = 14`
  `max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 7`
  `max_parallel_workers = 14`
  `max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 7`

  With a transactional workload you normally want to optimize throughput, and parallel query is bad for that. It makes queries faster at the expense of extra resources. Do you want one accidental big query to hog 8 of your 32 cores, when you need them for the transactional workload? No.

  Set `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` to 0 and leave `max_parallel_maintenance_workers` to something more moderate like the default 2.
- `wal_buffers = 1MB`

  It might not matter with your workload, but there is no benefit in setting it so small. Leave it at its default value -1.
- `checkpoint_timeout = 5min`
  `max_wal_size = 4GB`

  Now here is the biggest potential for tuning a write-heavy workload. Fewer checkpoints mean fewer writes.  Set `max_wal_size` large (dozens of GB is just fine) and crank up `checkpoint_timeout` to half an hour or more.

  The only price you are paying is a little more disk space and long recovery time in the unlikely event of a crash.
- `wal_keep_segments = 400`

  Replication slots are more effective.

One additional parameter you might contemplate is setting `synchronous_commit = off`. If you can afford losing half a second of committed transactions in the unlikely event of a crash, that is an easy way to boost performance.

Comment: thanks on the above. I have a master and slave setup with the master being significantly more in terms of CPUs and memory. I read that setting the max_worker stuff has to be the same on the slave and with the slave only having half of the amount of cores thought that was necessary.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation on a connection pooler, I have seen pgBouncer and pgPool but our application hits 2 different databases mainly and we experience alot of idles in transactions at the moment because the session hangs on one of the databases due to a large query and doesnt return. We also use prepared queries as well (again thought it was wise to set it to the same amount of max_connections). We have multiple app servers hitting the DB master server. The server mainly is under pressure on big SELECTs and the parallel workers get used for some of these.

Comment: You can certainly set `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` different on primary and standby. Your application should have a built-in connection pool, but if that does not work, use pgBouncer. You will never have a chance of good performance with long `idle in transaction`. Fix your application!

Comment: thanks, I can add the idle_in_transaction_timeout so the queries would get cancelled but not the answer. SELECTs looks to be the ones hardest hitting. Was looking at more the servers memory usage for postgres being low (using only half) and thought the system would perform better if it was using more (not all for obvious reasons). We do have replication slots in use as well. Id say the system is under more stress on reads as opposed to writes. Looked online tuning websites (pgTune/Cybertec but their configs looked vastly different to what i have in place.

Comment: @rdbmsNoob "*The server mainly is under pressure on big SELECTs*" - You likely have a software issue then, more than a hardware / configuration issue. You should find out why those `SELECTs` are taking long (`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` is your friend) and fix them. Also your database doesn't sound *as transactional* as I initially was thinking (less than 100 DML transactions per minute). Any way to roughly quantify the amount (in GBs) of data being changed over that hour timeframe?...that would be relevant to Lauren's suggestion on tuning the `max_wal_size`.

Comment: @J.D. think the SELECTs taking long are combined with the sheer dataset we have, will be looking at archiving where possible. The database is still heavily transactional but we mainly see issues with selects on large datasets. Looking at it via pgBadger for example the most frequent/time consuming queries etc.

Comment: @rdbmsNoob That's still a software issue in regards to architecting your database design and / or the queries themselves. There's a number of ways to architect both, to improve the performance of loading and processing *large datasets*. Also many people tend to over-estimate their data size and under-estimate how big *large* actually is, when facing common performance problems. 1.5 TB is a pretty decently sized amount of data, but only if it were all in 1 Table (which I've worked with data at that scale), and it doesn't matter how big a Table is, only how much data you need from it at a time.

Comment: @rdbmsNoob E.g. if your Table has 10 billion rows in it, but your queries only need about 100,000 at a time, that should be relatively quick to accomplish. But again, I'd recommend using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to help you go from *I think* to *I know* what the problem is. As it's pretty common for people to skip over that step and miss the actual issues of their queries, thinking their data volume is the problem, and under-estimating the abilities of a modern database system.